# Appending nested list data to another nested list based on user input

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

I am trying to work out how to append data from one nested list to another. I am familiar with .append(). My problem arises because I want the user to be able to choose which piece of data to append.

So I have two nested lists which look like this:

```
list_one = [['example', 'example', '000', 'example'],['example', 'example', '000', 'example']]
```

I want something like this...
`user_input = input("Enter a number: ")`
If the user entered 1 I would like to take data from the nested list at that index and append that data to another list.

I don't want the data to be sliced either. I want the whole `['example', 'example', '000', 'example']` to be appended to another list.

Comment: I don't understand which part you don't get. You understand the `append` method, so what's stopping you from doing `list_out.append(int(user_input))` ?

Comment: Say I had multiple lists within the nested list. I want the user to enter a number and based on what number they enter, whatever list is at that index within the nested list, I want to append that entire list to another nested list. Haha that sounded confusing. I can try and reword if that didn't make sense. I have a feeling I will need to use a for loop to iterate over all the items in the nested list I am trying to take data from. Correct me if I'm wrong though please

Comment: I'm not just trying to append user input to the nested list.

Comment: My bad, I meant append `list_one[int(user_input)]` ie taking the list that has the same index as the input given

Comment: ohhh so I could do something like:
list_two.append(list_one(int[user_input]))?

Answer (score 0):

```
list_one = [['example', 'example', '000', 'example'],
            ['example', 'example', '001', 'example']] 
list_out = []
user_input = input("Enter a number: ")
list_out.append(list_one[int(user_input)])
```

Comment: @youngdaggerdick consider accepting the best answer so that the question can be closed. cheers

Comment: @Sandy.Arv The question can be closed without any answer being accepted.

Comment: did not know that.. well, we learn new things every day :) @Anthon

Comment: Please avoid code-only answers. I advice you to read [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Anthon: we don't "close" answers here simply when they are resolved - only when they are off-topic. I see you're a 15K user, so perhaps this is just a matter of word-choice. While you're right that OPs are not obligated to accept an answer, I think we generally prefer it, since it marks the question as resolved, the metadata for which feeds into the search system and the API.

Comment: @halfer  I did not suggest that. I just indicated to Sandy.Arv that there is no need for **this** question to have an accepted answer for **this** question to be closed (as it should). Nor is it necessary for any other question that should be closed for any other reasons. It would actually be useful if this question would have no answers in the first place when it gets closed.